# redirect in asp.net mvc 2 controller initialize routine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to redirect from any controller to the login page if the session becomes null, i tried this  but its not working

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) {
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    if (Session["FirstName"] == null) {
        ret.msg = Resources.Resources.error_session_expired;
        ret.status = "danger";
        RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account", new {
            area = ""
        }); // <-- i added a return in front of this, but it was red underlined
    }
}
```

what is the best way to do this

Comment: where is the `Initialize` at?

Comment: Why was the `return` red underlined? Why is the session becoming null?

Comment: I don't know what this is trying to do, but it seems a better concept is to use an [ActionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: [`Controller.Initialize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) shouldn't be used for this. As you noticed, in the first place it's a `void`, so you can't return anything from it Use an `ActionFilter` instead like @Erik suggests.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I need to redirect to the login  page of the session is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an action filter:

```
public class RedirectIfNullSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["FirstName"] == null) 
    {
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
        new RouteValueDictionary 
          { 
            { "controller", "Account" }, 
            { "action", "Login" } 
          });
    }
  }
}
```

Then apply it to your controllers:

```
[RedirectIfNullSession]
public class MyController : Controller
{
  ....
```